# QT окно и потоки

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt5

Времени суток доброго. Столкнулся с проблемой, что при нажатии на кнопку и запуске цикла(долгосрочного) зависает полностью окно(оно и не мудрено). Вопрос состоит в чем, как в QT в объекте создать ОТДЕЛЬНЫЙ поток с функцией ЭТОГО же объекта?

```
std::thread thr(func);
thr.detach();
```

не работает.

```
QFuture <void> thr =  QtConcurrent::run(func);
```

не работает.

UPD
Пример

Класс

```
class Human{
    String name;
    void singSong(){
        for(;;) cout << name << " : Lya lya lya" << endl;
    }
    void sing(){
        thread thr(singSong);
        thr.detach();
    }
}
```

Main

```
Human oleg = new Human();
Human vasya = new Human();
oleg.sing();
vasya.sing();
```

Нужно именно так! Никак иначе. Нужно чтобы функция(sing) создавала поток в котором будет ДРУГАЯ функция(singSong) крутиться, пока не закончится.

Хотелось бы , чтобы это так работало, но мне постоянно выдает невнятные варнинги и ошибки при компиляции.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Надо правильно вызвать  `run`:

```
class Human {
    String name;
public:
    void singSong() {
        for(;;) cout << name << " : Lya lya lya" << endl;
    }
    void sing(){
        // Здесь this - объект класса, в котором находится нужная функция
        QtConcurrent::run(this, &Human::singSong);
    }
};

Human human;
human.sing();
```

Не забудьте в файле `pro` подключить модуль QtConcurrent к проекту:

```
QT += concurrent
```

Comment: К сожалению это не помогло. При компиляции выдало кучу ошибок.

Comment: @kifor4ik вы подключили модуль к проекту? Дополнил ответ

Comment: Да, модуль подключил. Qt 6.0.3

Comment: @kifor4ik должно работать, я проверил. Какие ошибки получаете? Покажите парочку верхних

Comment: Я решил проблему другим способом. В кратце мой проект - окно и есть функция долговыполняющаяся в цикле while, когда входило в цикл у меня погибало окно(зависало)
я добавил в конец цикла QCoreApplication::processEvents(); и это решило проблему.
Но ради интереса я вернул старый код и вот какая ошибка: + 
Я перешел на QT5 и там теперь другая проблема возникает.

QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTextDocument(0x26ba820), parent's thread is QThread(0x2748830), current thread is QThreadPoolThread(0x6f01c30)